# REGEXP_LIKE DB2 regex pattern

Tags: sql, regex, db2, regexp-like

I tried to query search pattern this my sql query but unable to get the result.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where REGEXP_LIKE(paramater,'^*RHEL[RHEL77435]','i')
```

my goal is to search pattern that start with first 4 character including * (***RHEL**) and contains any character input in meta-character[ ] and this case is (RHEL77435).

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where REGEXP_LIKE(paramater,'^*RH[RHEL77435]','i')
```

when I tried 2 character (RH) it works for me

expected output:

```
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
|      ruleid         |     parameter    |     Operating  |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------- |
|          1          |      *RHEL       |       Linux    |
|---------------------|------------------|----------------|
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The pattern you want to search for is unclear.

Comment: ok, I just added the expected out in table form

Comment: Add the table with existing data from which to select. The results only make sense with some input

Comment: Do you mean you need to find records starting with an asterisk, then `RHEL` substring and then any chars? Try `^[*]RHEL.*`

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew , yes it work for me, thanks . btw may I know why put dot and asterisk at the last ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `=`?

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE parameter = '*RHEL';
```

Or, if there could be additional characters after `'*RHEL'`, then use `LIK`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE parameter LIKE '*RHEL%';
```

Comment: The reason is I want to add more complex regex later on. But this one is confusing me, I tried to add condition in regex_like. First 3 characters works for me (RHE), but I when I tried to add more character it doesn't work.  I wonder if I can combine LIKE with REGEX_LIKE

Comment: @HydrogenUranium . .  This works for the sample data you have provided in the question.